# Regex finding models from product list

Tags: regex

I am trying to retrieve the product models from a list of product titles.

Since it is difficult to retrieve model from title, I decided starting from getting substrings with uppercase letters AND numbers (it can contains special characters also, but they are not necessary).

Some examples would be:

- Apple iPhone 8 Plus 64GB Tela Retina 5.5" 12MP/7MP iOS 11 - Prata
- Smart TV QLED de 55" Samsung **QN55Q7FAMP** com HDMI/USB/Wi-Fi Bivolt
- Smart TV QLED de 65" Samsung **QN55Q7FAMP** com HDMI/USB/Wi-Fi Bivolt
- MEMORIA DDR4 CRUCIAL 16GB/2400 CRUCIAL **BLS16G4D240FSE** BALLISTIX S
- MEMORIA DDR4 CRUCIAL 16GB/2400 CRUCIAL **BLS16G4D240FSB** BALLISTIX S
- MEMORIA DDR4 CRUCIAL 16GB/2400 CRUCIAL **BLS16G4D240FSC** BALLISTIX S
- MEMORIA DDR4 CRUCIAL 16GB/2400 CRUCIAL **CT16G4DFD824A** (SIN BLISTER
- Projetor LG MiniBeam **PW1500G** 1500 Lumens WXGA (1280x800) HDMI/USB

I know a lot of them will be captured with error. To avoid some errors, I am thinking in construct a dictionary of strings to ignore (like DDR4, xxGB, etc...)

I started trying with [this](https://regex101.com/r/1Ra5U5/1). I am getting words with uppercase AND/OR numbers. How to get words with BOTH (uppercase letters and numbers) and special characters (if they are there it is ok, but they are not necessary).

---

This was my first approach to solve the problem. Of course, another solutions using or not regex would be very welcome.

Comment: If you allow every character everything in your haystack is going to match. There is no pattern I can decipher in this text. (You could add more characters to your character class, the more you add though the loose you get and the more matches you will encounter).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to match blocks that contain at least one capital letter and one number?
So something like this ensures there is at least one capital and one number in the middle. You would need to use 'or' to make it work the other way too.

```
.+ ([A-Z1-9]*[A-Z]+[0-9]+[A-Z1-9]*) .+
```

Answer (score 0):

Though this is an old question, I found it intriguing and tried to come up with a suitable regex:

```
\s(?![A-Z]*DDR)([A-Z](([A-Z]|-)*[0-9]+([A-Z]|-)*)+)
```

The main assumption made is that model numbers all start with a letter. This means that inevitably some model numbers are missed out due to starting with a numeric digit. Some breakdown:

`\s` - Preceded by a space

`(?![A-Z]*DDR)` - Negative lookahead to skip all sequences that include **DDR**

The model number is composed of a HEAD and a TAIL.

**HEAD**:

`[A-Z]` - A single uppercase character

**TAIL**:

`([A-Z]|-)*` - Starts with zero or more of either an uppercase character or a dash

`[0-9]+` - Must include at least one numeric digit

`([A-Z]|-)*` - Ends with zero or more of either and uppercase character or a dash

`(([A-Z]|-)*[0-9]+([A-Z]|-)*)+` - The TAIL can have more tails attached

There are still false positives in there, but over 90% of the model numbers [from OP's sample data](https://regex101.com/r/1Ra5U5/1) have been picked up.